# Galaxy S 2 battery won't charge while being on

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, battery, charging

First of all, LOVE the Galaxy s2, even though it has some problems - which phone doesnt, right?

I've had the Samsung Galaxy S2 for 2 months. It worked fine. 
Since a week my phone won't charge the battery while being on. I would charge my battery almost every night. At night almost empty, I wake up and its full. Now a week ago I woke up and the battery had only 3 % left and it was VERY warm. Unplugged it, tried it again. Turned phone on and off... Nothing worked. When my phone died, I left it to cool and then charged it again in it's off state for a few hours. I turned it on and the battery was full again!

I use the original charger, I haven't changed anything since having the phone.

So now I can only charge my phone while it's off.. Not ideal...

Has anyone had the same problem?? Any advise is welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: I would try another USB charger and see if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try what Matthew said and also try to update the firmware on your phone via [Samsung's Kies updater](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/detail/supportPrdDetail.do?menu=SP01&prd_ia_cd=1903&prd_mdl_cd=GT-I9100LKAXEU&prd_mdl_name=GT-I9100&srchword=Galaxy+S+II), click on the firmware tab and download Kies and follow the instructions on the screen to update your firmware correctly. Your phone's firmware might be corrupted.

Answer (score 3):

Try factory reset. My phone had this issue as well. After a factory reset it worked fine. But be sure you back up all the important data first.

Comment: This should be the first thing to try when having almost any kind of problem with your Android phone. A factory reset will essentially eliminate anything software related causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me as well and I'm glad that I've found a thread related to it. Yes, the phone stop charging sometimes and then it will make the battery very hot. If you still charge it and somehow reached 100%, your battery will drain really fast. Let me share you guys what I did and actually made my battery last longer. When I noticed that the battery dropped from 100% to 95% in 3 minutes without doing anything, I waited until it reach 85% then turned the phone off. I charged it again up to a 100% (it actually took a long time again to charge it to 100%) and after that, my battery is performing a lot better. 12hours and it was just down to 75% with browsing, games and stuff, so this is the trick that I do whenever I encounter this issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's your charger (though you should try another just to discount this). I think it's a problem with the phone. My SGS2 is incredibly slow to charge, and sometimes even seems to lose a few % while charging if I actually use the phone. It also gets very hot (I dropped a temp widget on it and the highest record temp so far is 120F).

Try turning radios off but leave the phone on and see if your charge time improves. I'd do them one at a time to see which one is actually the problem child. I haven't exactly isolated mine, but personally I think it's the HSPA+.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume it's related to battery stats.  If they got screwed up then the phone can think it's drained when it's full and tries to charge (creating the heat).  A series of full drains and charges should help, especially if the stats are cleared first.  You should be able to do this from ClockworkMod Recovery if you have it.