# Samsung Galaxy S4: After 5.0.1 update phone only charges when switched-off

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, charging

While my phone was updating it was plugged in by the wall and charging. After the upgrade the battery was drained by the evening, and when I plugged it in to charge again, nothing happened.

- I plugged it into my computer and still nothing.
- I removed the battery and left it out for a few hours and thereafter, tried to charge again but still nothing.
- I switched-off the phone, plugged it in and then I got a battery with a lightning bulb, and it vibrates every 40 seconds or so.
- I left it overnight and it charged to 100%.

How can I fix this problem so that the phone charges while powered on, and gets recognized by my computer again?

Comment: Related: [Galaxy S 2 battery won't charge while being on](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/12690/16575)

Comment: Hi! I edited your question so that certain points (steps you took) can be read and focused easily. I also removed the very first line since you didn't add which questions or similar problem did you read, so it was unnecessary info in its current form. Do rollback or [edit] furthermore if you think the edit is unjust. :)